# maple - very big error or matrixes in physics package

Tags: maple

I try to make friends physics package and matrixes. But I am faced with difficulties. To be more specific, to consider a code:

```
with(Physics)

Setup(mathematicalnotation = true)

Coordinates(X)

Setup(tensors = A[mu](X))

PDEtools:-declare(A(X), p0(X), pm(X), pp(X), pt(X), U(X), m5(X))
```

And then I create a matrix:

```
pt := proc (X) options operator, arrow; Matrix(2, 2, [[p0(X), sqrt(2)*pp(X)], [sqrt(2)*pm(X), -p0(X)]]) end proc;

NULL;
```

[It displays as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l8eW.png)

Why do p0, pp, pm become function only one variable x1?

Interestingly that maple understands
[the next matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F99am.png)

Why is only one variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this one, it is frequently useful to consult the documentation. In the help page for [Coordinates](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Physics/Coordinates), you read "The Coordinates command also sets an alias for a capital letter X to represent a list of coordinates ..." So: you type X and that automatically expands to x1, x2, x3, x4, while this sequence of variables *is displayed* as a single X. BUT, when you define a procedure, as in pt := proc(X) .... end proc, the X you see there is just a dummy representing (only one) procedure's parameter.

That answers your question: you see p0, pp, pm as functions of only one variable because pt is defined as a function of only one variable: when you execute pt(X) only the first element in the sequence, that is x1, is used, the other three are discarded. From context I understand that what you want to define is pt := proc(x1, x2, x3, x4) .... end proc. Then use it as pt(X) and you will see p0, pp, pm as functions of the four variables, which in turn *are displayed* as the single capital X.

Edgardo S. Cheb-Terrab

Physics, Differential Equations and Mathematical Functions, Maplesoft.